# List all commands that Alt-F2 offers

Tags: bash

I'd like to obtain a list of all commands that can be run via <kbd>Alt-F2</kbd>.

So for shell commands this would be:

```
compgen -c
```

I need something similar, but only for graphical commands. So e.g. `rhythmbox` should be on that list, but `rm` shouldn't.

Comment: I guess anything in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` can be run via Alt+F2.

Comment: Who said `rm` can't be run via Alt-F2?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -executable 2>/dev/null | while read -r c; do
  ldd "$c" | grep -q -m 1 libX11.so
  [[ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 ]] && echo "${c##*/}"
done
```

---

See: `man find`, `help while`, `help read`, `man ldd`, `man grep`, `man bash`

Comment: +1 but note that there is no guarantee that graphical programs will show `libX11.so` in `ldd`, they can use a wrapper over `libX11.so`..in that case it would not be included..

Comment: Thanks, but your variant takes ages to complete. I was hoping for some DBUS call that other apps like gnome-do would use. In fact, the same one that Unity's menu uses would be fine.

Comment: Can you add an example please?